# What is the difference between "new Number(...)" and "Number(...)" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, language-features, language-design

In Javascript, one of the [reliable ways to convert a string to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) is the `Number` constructor:

```
var x = Number('09'); // 9, because it defaults to decimal
```

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381253/what-side-effects-does-the-keyword-new-have-in-javascript), I started wondering — what is the difference between the above and:

```
var x =new Number('09');
```

`Number` certainly looks better, but it seems like a slightly inappropriate use of a constructor.  Are there any side effects or any difference to using it without the **new**?   If there is no difference, why not, and what is the purpose of **new**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the first case, you are using the [Number Constructor Called as a Function](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.7.1), as described in the Specification, that will simply perform a type conversion, returning you a `Number` primitive.

In the second case, you are using the [`Number` Constructor](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.7.2) to make a *`Number` object*:

```
var x = Number('09');
typeof x; // 'number'

var x = new Number('09');
typeof x; // 'object'

Number('1') === new Number('1'); // false
```

The difference may be subtle, but I think it's important to notice how *wrapper objects* act on primitive values.

Comment: To be fair, `new Number('1') === new Number('1')` is also `false`, but I otherwise agree with you :)

Comment: Right, because that will compare two different object references.

Comment: @Richard Szalay - but, `Number('1') ===  Number('1')` is `true`, which illustrates @CMS's point.

Answer (score 4):

`Number` returns a primitive number value. Yeah, it's a bit odd that you can use a constructor function as a plain function too, but that's just how JavaScript is defined. Most of the language built-in types have weird and inconsistent extra features like this thrown in.

`new Number` constructs an explicit boxed `Number` object. The difference:

```
typeof Number(1)      // number
typeof new Number(1)  // object
```

In contrast to Java's boxed primitive classes, in JavaScript explicit `Number` objects are of **absolutely no use**.

I wouldn't bother with either use of `Number`. If you want to be explicit, use `parseFloat('09')`; if you want to be terse, use `+'09'`; if you want to allow only integers, use `parseInt('09', 10)`.

Comment: +1, wish I could accept two answers as correct, since both are fully correct and contain unique helpful information.  I didn't know about using `+` with no number preceding it.

Answer (score 0):

SpiderMonkey-1.7.0:

```
js> typeof new Number('09');
object
js> typeof Number('09');
number
```

Answer (score 0):

Number (without new) doesn't seem to result exactly in a primitive. In the following example the anyMethod() is called (if in the Number prototype).

```
Number(3).anyMethod()
```

Whereas

```
3.anyMethod()
```

will not work.