# Javascript "==" operator lies

Tags: javascript

The following confuses me greatly. As noted in the comments, the compares seem to work by themselves, but when put together they don't

The while should run for all days in the same month, then increment i by one, then start over again.

I have laced the whole sequence up with console.log to try to figure it out, but it doesn't make any sense. Everything seems to equal one another, but still fails the "==" test in the while statement.

```
  var i=0;
  var currentdate = 0;
  var currentmonth = 0;
  var opensmonth = 0;
  var opens = [
  { "date":"3/30/2006","zip":"30038","latitude":"33.676358","longitude":"-84.15381"},
  { "date":"4/31/2006","zip":"30519","latitude":"34.089419","longitude":"-83.94701"}
  ];
  intid = setInterval("stepthrough()", 250);
  function stepthrough() {
    //figure out first date.
    if (currentdate == 0) { // we've not been run before
      currentdate = opens[0]["date"];
      currentmonth = currentdate.split("/", 1);
      console.log("Current Month: >" + currentmonth +"<");
    }
    console.log("Current month: " + currentmonth + " And opensdate: " + opens[i]["date"].split("/", 1));

    // 
    // TWILIGHT ZONE ENTERED.
    // 
    if (currentmonth == 3 ) { 
      console.log("Current month equals 3."); // PASSES
    }
    if (opens[i]["date"].split("/", 1) == 3) {
      console.log("Opens date equals 3."); // PASSES
    }
    // BOTH THE ABOVE TESTS PASS IN CHROME AND SAFARI WHAT THE F*$K JAVASCRIPT

    while(opens[i]["date"].split("/", 1) == currentmonth) { // WHY DOESNT THIS WORK I HATE COMPUTERS
      console.log("Trying to add a point one."); 
      addpoint(i);
      i++; 
      console.log("Trying to add a point."); 
    }

    //set the date for next iteration
    currentdate = opens[i]["date"];
    currentmonth = currentdate.split("/", 1);
    console.log ("Current date is now: " + currentdate + " and current month is now: " + currentmonth);
    jQuery('div#date').text(currentdate);

    //if (i>=5000) {
    if (!opens[i]["date"]) {
      console.log("Clearing interval");
      clearInterval(intid);
      //jQuery('div#date').text("Limited at 5000 records")
    }
  }
```

Comment: try using `parseInt(stringValue, 10)`.

Comment: What happens if you use `===` in the `// WHY DOESNT THIS WORK` line? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use/359509#359509) suggests that `==` is evil and can't be trusted.

Comment: i honestly don't see a question here.

Comment: Still working on this, but a key part of the issue here is that `"1/2/11".split('/', 1)` evaluates to `["1"]` - but for some reason surely explained in another SO question, `["1"] == 1` in Javascript.

Comment: I wish I got this much rep for asking jacked questions like this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but you should do `setInterval(stepthrough, 250);` instead of `setInterval("stepthrough()", 250);`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote @zengr for editing the title of this question, which even after I answered I assumed was a polemical statement ("Javascript is lies! Lies!")

Comment: @nrabinowitz Haha, I felt the same!

Comment: The === didn't work, but parseInt() did. Adding the [0] to the split probably would have as well, though I didn't try it.

Thanks to all for responding. I LEARNT A THING.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem: `["1"] == 1` in Javascript, because of the implicit conversions @Matt describes. But `["1"] != ["1"]` in Javascript, because you're comparing two arrays, and thus two objects, and object comparisons are only true if they point to the *same* object, not if they point to two identical objects.

When you assign with `.split('/', 1)`, you're getting an array like `['3']`, not the string `"3"` (as I think you might be assuming). So:

```
currentmonth = currentdate.split("/", 1); // currentmonth is ["3"]
currentmonth == 3; // true, as described above
opens[i]["date"].split("/", 1) == 3; // true, because left-hand evals to ["3"]
opens[i]["date"].split("/", 1) == currentmonth; 
// false, because you're comparing two arrays - ["3"] != ["3"]
```

To fix this with your current code, you can just get the string, not the array, like this:

```
currentmonth = currentdate.split("/")[0]; // currentmonth is "3"
opens[i]["date"].split("/")[0] == currentmonth; // true, both sides are "3"
```

Comment: I should have checked the rest of the answers before proceeding, I just came to the same conclusion.  Good answer.

Comment: I've added some [details of my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056317/javascript-operator-lies/8056914#8056914), but credit goes to you for spotting the array problem first.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript typing is implicit.  This means if it thinks you are trying to treat something as a number, it will do it's best to treat that object as a number, even if it is, say, a boolean, or a string.

When doing standard `==`, JavaScript will use implicit conversions to try and match types.  This often results in unexpected comparison results.

If you want to force strong comparisons, you must use the `===` operator.

That being said, if you are examining the 'number' representation of a string, e.g. "123", and want to use strong comparisons, you must convert it to a number using parseInt(str, 10);

For some examples on implicit typing in action, see the [JavaScript truth table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224) answer.

Comment: Good answer, but doesn't actually explain the cause of the problem, just best practice.

Comment: `Number` [constructor called as a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381399/what-is-the-difference-between-new-number-and-number-in-javascript/2381580#2381580) also works.

Answer (score 1):

Please upvote [nrabinowitz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056317/javascript-operator-lies/8056529#8056529) because he was first and it is correct.

However, I do want to add some details on the underlying problem and how Javascript handles `==` implicit conversions between Arrays, Numbers, and Strings.

**To summarize**: Each type has slightly different rules when using `==` with different types.  Arrays are converted to primitive value when compared to Number or String, but not when compared with another Array.

**Detail**:

1. `String.split` returns an Array.
2. Strings and Numbers are raw [types](http://es5.github.com/#Type) in Javascript.  The others are Boolean, Object, Null, and Undefined.
3. Array is type **Object**
4. `==` follows the "[Abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)" (`x == y`)
5. **In your first two comparisons**, since one of the types (`3`) is a Number, your condition falls under the following rule:

   > If Type(x) is either **String** or **Number** and Type(y) is Object,
   >   return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).

   In other words, it converts the array `["3"]` to 3 and compares it with 3 — **true** (see the [docs on ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1))
6. In the last **case that you say is broken**, it falls under the first rule, ("Type(x) is the same as Type(y)" — they are both **Object**.  Then it evaluates the following rule:

   > Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
7. They contain the same value, but are not the same *object* (each is a *different* result of a call to `String.split`), so the result is **false**.

To illustrate:

```
console.log("3 == [3]?", 3 == [3]); // true
console.log("3 == ['3']?", 3 == ['3']);  // true
console.log("'3' == [3]?", "3" == [3]); // true
console.log("'3' == ['3']?", '3' == ['3']); // true
console.log("[3] == [3]?", [3] == [3]); // false
console.log("['3'] == ['3']?", ['3'] == ['3']); // false - NOT SAME OBJECT

var a = ['3'];
var b = a; // SAME OBJECT

console.log("a == b?", a == b); // true!
```

The solution, as @nrabinowitz says, is to simply add `[0]` to the end of the split call so that the value is the first element (a String) instead of the Array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this just to know if it's a integer vs string failure ?

This is not a nice solution but it gives a clue.

```
while(opens[i]["date"].split("/", 1) + "str" == currentmonth + "str")
```

Comment: i would use `parseInt` instead.