# Why is new Number(8) not exactly equal to 8?

Tags: javascript

alert returns false instead of true? as type is Number for both x and y and as per documentation of `===` its a strict compare which checks type along with value.

```
var x=8;
var y=new Number(8);
alert(typeof x);
alert(y===x);//false
```

PS : new to JavaScript still understanding the base concepts.

Comment: If you declare y like that, it becomes the object type.

Comment: Welcome to javascript, you are going to have a fun journey :-)

Comment: have you check typeof y? it is object

Comment: A bunch of similar questions that could probably have answered your question: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+new+Number . Especially http://stackoverflow.com/q/2381399/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4719320/218196,

Comment: I see you've already decided what answer is the best. But you might wanna read my more elaborate answer since you're new to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive types *Boolean*, *Number* and *String*, each have a corresponding object representation, which can be created via `new Boolean`, `new String`, etc. As I already hinted at, those return **objects**. An *Object* is a different *data type* than a *Number*, so strict comparison will return `false`.

However, those constructors are not widely used, because, as you found out, they don't play well with primitives. A  `Number` object that encapsulates the same value as a *primitive* number value is not (strictly) equal to said primitive value.

What you might see more often is the use of the `Number` function without `new`. If called without `new`, `Number` simply performs *type conversion*, to a *primitive* number value.

---

So why do we have `Number`, `String` and `Boolean` objects at all?

It turns out you are using such objects all the time without (probably) knowing, e.g. when you do

```
"primitive".substring(0, 5)
```

In JavaScript, only *objects* can have properties. Primitive values cannot have properties. And yet you can call the `substring` method as if it was a property of the value. That's because JavaScript does something called *auto-boxing*. When you are trying to use a primitive values like an object (e.g. by accessing a property), JavaScript internally converts the primitive temporarily to its equivalent object version.

Answer (score 1):

That is because when instantiating using `new` the type is `object` even if that object's name is Number.

```
typeof y === "object"
```

Answer (score 0):

Y is an object not a number. The new keyword references to objects. So y is a number object with the value 8.

Try `alert(typeof y);`

Answer (score 0):

when you make `var y=new Number(8);` it becomes a object not a number and because of that `===` fails to compare both as same.

```
var x=8;
var y=new Number(8);
alert(typeof x);//number
alert(typeof y);//object
alert(y===x);//false
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, alert does always return `undefined`. But it prints stuff on screen. `console.log` gives you more detailed and colorful info though.

This problem has two parts. First one is that numbers are normally not `Number` instance. The second is that two objects (two instances) of any kind are never exactly equal:

```
{}=={}  // false
```

#### Not `Number` problem

Now to the `Number` issue. Although all numbers in JavaScript are technically a `Number`, javascript does not treat them like that and they are **not number instance**. This is something I don't like very much, but it's what it is. If you create number by instance, it behaves as non-object value:

```
5 instanceof Number  //false
typeof 5 // "number"
```

Creating number with `Number` constructor creates an object, that acts as a `Number`:

```
new Number(5) instanceof Number  //true
typeof new Number(5) // "object"
```

It should be noted that this object is actually not very special. You can make your own number class:

function MyNumber(val) {
       this.number = 1*val||0;
   }
   MyNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() {
       return this.number;
   }

This will work just as `Number` object does. Of course, just as `Number` object, this is lost when you do a math operation:

typeof (MyNumber(6)+MyNumber(4)) // "number"

#### Two object instances are never exactly equal

This is actually useful feature. But it betrays you here:

```
new Number(5)===new Number(5) //false
```

**`Number` instance will never be exactly equal to anything but itself.**