# Object vs normal function

Tags: javascript

// Code Starts

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log(this.name); //Output 1    
    console.log(this); //Output 2    
}
var p1 = new Person("Object_Shashank");
var p2 = Person("Function_Shashank");
```

// Code Ends

**p1 :**

- Output 1: Object_Shashank
- Output 2: Person {name: "Object_Shashank"}

**p2 :**

- Output 1: Function_Shashank
- Output 2: Window {speechSynthesis: SpeechSynthesis, caches: CacheStorage, localStorage: Storage, sessionStorage: Storage, webkitStorageInfo: DeprecatedStorageInfo…}

Can someone please explain "p2: Output 2"

Comment: `Person()` = `window.Person()`

Comment: you've forgotten `new` keyword before `Person`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [What is the difference between "new Number(...)" and "Number(...)" in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2381399)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "new Number(...)" and "Number(...)" in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381399/what-is-the-difference-between-new-number-and-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

It prints the `window` object because the `this` references the window object.

```
function Person(name){   
    this.name=name;    
    console.log(this.name); //Output 1    
    console.log(this);  //Output 2    <-- this `this` will point to the object it belongs to ,  which in this case of p1  is Object_Shashank while for p2 is window
}    
var p1=new Person("Object_Shashank");   
var p2=Person("Function_Shashank");  // Equivalent to p2 = window.Person("Function_Shashank")
```

*Edit* . Added the code example

Comment: Thank You. It is helpful