# difference between Var and new

Tags: javascript, new-operator, var, instanceof

```
var a = 10
var b = new Number(10)

console.log(a instanceof Number)
console.log(b instanceof Number)
```

can anyone please let me know what is the difference between above two declaration and definition of a and b.

Comment: Maybe this post can help explain [**new Number()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381399/what-is-the-difference-between-new-number-and-number-in-javascript) The rest I'm sure will make sense after you understand `new Number()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between string literals and String objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-string-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: poorly worded title, both `a` and `b` are `var`

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly stating that you are creating a new number with `new Number(10)` creates a new [**wrapper object**](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/javascripts-primitive-wrapper-objects.html) for the number, whereas simply defining a number as a variable creates a [**integer primitive value**](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/). As such, you get differing results when checking their **[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**:

```js
var a = 10;
var b = new Number(10);

console.log(typeof a);
console.log(typeof b);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Pretty sure it creates an number primitive value... the rest seems right though.

Comment: Whoops, slight oversight on my part :P Fixed :)

Comment: thanks buddy for the clarification but when we declare var a=10, we find a number of methods against a variable but without a constructor . so can you explain this one too as , there is no integer concept in javascript and JavaScript numbers are always stored as double precision floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The first creates a primitive. The other an object.

The primary uses for the Number object are:

1) If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN.

2) In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

In theory there is a difference but in practice none. The JavaScript engine automagicly boxes a primitive to an object when it needs to be an object.

```
var number = 42;
// calling .toFixed will 'box' the primitive into a number object,
// run the method and then 'unbox' it back to a primitive
console.log( number.toFixed(2) );
```

The only usage I've found is if you want to return a primitive from a constructor function.

```
function Foo() {
    return 42;
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); // foo is instance of Foo

function Bar() {
    return new Number(42);
}

var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar); // bar is instance of Number
```

remind that

```
new Number(10) == new Number(10) return false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration is like primitive datatype.

While in your second declaration where you used `new Number(10)`, it is considered like a wrapper function or `class` to preserve your number in an `object`.

To see the actual difference, check now the actual type of your variables in both cases:

```
console.log(typeof(a)) //should give you "number"
console.log(typeof(b)) //should give you "object"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var` keyword is just a simple declaration of a variable. The `new` keyword is used to generate a new `object` of some type. You'll need to look into objects in programming in general in order to fully understand them.